# Do all ISAs and their implementation require word-alignment?

Tags: cpu-word, alignment

Does Intel's IA-32 require word alignment? if not, which are the ISAs and their chips that require word-alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Intel x86 based chips accept misaligned memory references. SPARC based chips don't. There are other ISAs also which strictly don't accept misaligned memory references.